# Get magento header description in schema Product description in view.phtml

Tags: php, magento, seo, schema, magento-1.8

In the header I have the following code for meta description.

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
```

I am trying to get this description as my schema product description as follows in the view.pthml file

```
<meta itemprop="description" name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
```

However "Description" it shows up as a blank on the google rich snippets tool (GRST)

When I enclose and tag the meta description in the head.phtml file

```
<meta itemprop="description" name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
```

with a `<span itemscope itemtype="Http://Schema.Org/Product" >` the description shows up on the GRST, but of course breaks the other product itemtype thats on view.phtml.

So how do I get the description in the header to show as my schema product description in view.phtml?

Note: the default meta description is not used (blank) a extension called creare SEO creates the meta description based on attributes.

Comment: This is what fixed the problem

    <?php $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head'); echo $description=$headBlock->getDescription(); ?>" />

Thanks to [Amit Bera][1] reference [post][2]


  [1]: http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4564/amit-bera
  [2]: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31581/get-meta-description-in-schema-product-description/31582?noredirect=1#comment42426_31582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what fixed the problem

```
<?php $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head'); echo $description=$headBlock->getDescription(); ?>" />
```

Thanks to [Amit Bera](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4564/amit-bera), reference [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31581/get-meta-description-in-schema-product-description/31582?noredirect=1#comment42426_31582)

Comment: $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head'); show error.